# Logging into multiple accounts using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer

Basically I have a puppeteer setup that logs into google and changes the profile picture, then logs out. With the current setup, you need to manually edit the username and password fields in the script. I have an accounts.txt file with gmail:password lists. I was wondering how I could automate this process and log into all the accounts in the txt file and change the profile pictures. Thanks!

Comment: You can use worker or cluster (puppeteer-cluster) and make loop to automate that.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could use a loop to change the username and password fields though.

Comment: I write an answer with the code below, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

This code is just an example to automating login process to Twitter.
Please NOTE: This code isn't working properly as the Twitter required CAPTCHA process.

```
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster')
const twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/login'

;(async () => {
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
        maxConcurrency: 2,
        puppeteerOptions: {
            headless: false
        }
    })

    const usernameInput = 'main [type="text"]'
    const passwordInput = 'main [type="password"]'
    const loginButton = 'main [role="button"]'

    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: [username, password] }) => {
        await page.goto(twitterURL)
        await page.waitForSelector(usernameInput)
        await page.click(usernameInput)
        await page.keyboard.type(username)
        await page.waitForSelector(passwordInput)
        await page.click(passwordInput)
        await page.keyboard.type(password)
        await page.waitForSelector(loginButton)
        await page.screenshot({path: `beforelogin_${username}.png`})
        await Promise.all([
            page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}),
            page.click(loginButton)
        ])
        await page.screenshot({path: `afterlogin_${username}.png`})
        // Store screenshot, do something else
    });

    cluster.queue(['realDonaldTrump', 'BlackLivesMatter1234'])
    cluster.queue(['elonmusk', 'TeslaStillCrashed'])
    cluster.queue(['justinbieber', 'SelenaGomezMyGF'])
    // many more account

    await cluster.idle()
    await cluster.close()

})()
```